# How to create a url that opens a tab downloads a file and closes the tab

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create an URL that when clicked upon opens a tab, downloads a file, and closes that tab. Do you guys know how to do it?
Following is an example: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/850262728428748830/937385812671209502/vineboom.ogg

I am quite new to this and overwhelmed to know where to start. Can somebody assist me with this?
I tried messing with Anchor tag but that is not the answer. According to my research figured it has something to do with NodeJS and ExpressJS. Still no idea of what to do.

Comment: Simply put the file as the link target (`href`). If the link target is not viewable by the browser, then downloading is the triggered action. To open it in a new tab use `target="_BLANK"`

Comment: yeah but that's front end, and won't work on my use case

Comment: Then pheraps explain the usecase in the question and why it requires a backend solution.

Comment: Say we generate a url for a file in the manner site.com/img/download/12345678, where the number in the URL is an ID of that image. Now I will send this link to my client in email on which they will click to obtain a direct download of the file upon clicking the URL.

Comment: Yeah that would require a backend setup which I can't help with. I'm just suggesting to edit your question and make the situation clear and get better answers. Also because StackOverflow is a library if Q&A and future people who face a similar problem are likely to search and find yours.

Comment: nvm Figured it out, uploading the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Create require variables as shown and then created a function with whatever name you like, here I am using "onLoad" as the name. This function just checks for the file name in the URL's file parameter specified then tries to find it in the server.

```js
var url_string = window.location; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var file = url.searchParams.get("file");
var dFile = file;

function onLoad() {
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

hiddenElement.href = `${dFile}`;
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = `${dFile}`;
hiddenElement.click();
close()
}
```

Make sure to add onLoad function into the body with event listener of "onload"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
```